# Find location by inputting a zipcode on an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, slider, zipcode

I hope someone can help or at least point me in the right direction. I'm currently building an iPhone application that requires the input of a zip code to find a location. For example - if the user opens the app the first thing they see is a text box that requires them to input a 5 digit number (zip code) to find various businesses near that location. There is also a slider bar that has 5mi to 100mi radius. So, once the zip code input and the user has selected how much mileage and pressed the submit button, it should show the lists of businesses that are local to that area. Does that make sense?

Thanks a bunch everyone.

Comment: and you are talking about US zip codes, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all zip code does not map specifically to one location . It may refer to disjoint  sets of location as well (this happens in India ) One zip code like 400093 refers to diffrent place in India and might refer some different location in Korea  . There is no central server which could provide you with these specification. check for google API [(check here for google API)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/) to look for alternatives .

For your use case I would suggest you to look Four square API. get user co-ordinates , use geo location to detect their place or directly call four square api to get the useful information. 
[FourSqaure API](https://developer.foursquare.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your app, or make a web-service that will get the imput zip code and return the region.

It's a huge work. In couple of words:

Make a plist file that will have as keys all the zip codes you can load into it. [Take a look here, they are not few.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ZIP_code_prefixes) And set the values as the region names.

Once you have the zip code, you can find the region. Then, depending on the user's selected range, you can present the closest regions.

Also [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code), for detailed explanation of zip codes' formatting. You will have to learn a bit in order to be able to detect closest regions of a selected zip code.

As a fast, but not secure way - you can find a free web service that does the job (takes zip, gives region), without building your own server-side (or method in the app), but as I said, it's not secure.

Work.